# bats/bats:v1.4.1, curlimages/curl:7.73.0 these image are in grafana helm chart but when I describe the pod its not listed

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I deployed promtheus and grafana using official helm chart.

- bats/bats:v1.4.1
- curlimages/curl:7.73.0
  these image are in grafana helm chart but when I describe the pod these images are not listed.

I know that details mentioned in `spec.containers` are only visible when we describe the pod. So how can I check whether these images are really used by grafana. or more pricisely why we use these two images.

This is the part of values file

```
testFramework:
  enabled: true
  image: "bats/bats"
  tag: "v1.4.1"
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  securityContext: {}
```

```
downloadDashboardsImage:
  repository: curlimages/curl
  tag: 7.85.0
  sha: ""
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: Are you describing the correct pod? Check that he bats/bats container runs on:
{{- if .Values.testFramework.enabled }}
{{- $root := . }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {{ include "grafana.fullname" . }}-test
  labels:
    {{- include "grafana.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test-success
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded"
  namespace: {{ include "grafana.namespace" . }}

Comment: I suspect it a ephemeral image. It runs test and then its destroyed

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 helm template <chart> --generate-name | grep "image:"
```

to list the images that will be used. Or

```
 helm template <chart> --generate-name --values <values.yml> | grep "image:"
```

if you have an override values.yml file like:

```
   testFramework:
       enabled: false
```

in the second case bats/bats should not show up.